# Express problematic middleware - cookies access and memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, middleware

I am using express with cookieParser(). My client have the following cookie: `App.Debug.SourceMaps`.
I wrote the following middleware:

```
app.get('/embed/*/scripts/bundle-*.js', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies['App.Debug.SourceMaps'] === 'true') {
        var newUrl = req.url.replace(/(bundle-.*\.js)$/g, 'bundle.js');
        res.redirect(newUrl);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Two problems:

1. Do I access to 'App.Debug.SourceMaps' correctly? I know that I should access cookies like that: req.cookies.name, but my cookie name contains '.'
2. After adding this middleware, I experienced drastic performance issues. My CPU reached to 100% and I had memory leaks. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the bracket notation is perfectly acceptable, and in fact, it is more commonly used for accessing cookies.
2. Theres nothing particularly wrong with your code, it all depends on what happens after that redirect.